# Using Ruby's log with 2 Arguments

Tags: ruby, math, logging

I'm using the ruby Math.log function and passing it two arguments and I'm getting some sort of error for that.

```
puts Math.log(10, 10)
```

The error i get:

```
log': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

The docs say that's how it's supposed to work?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Math.html#method-c-log

Comment: You're referring to Ruby 2.0 docs, and running it under 1.9.3-p429 and 2.0.0-p247 it works: `Math.log(10, 10) # => 1.0`. Perhaps you're not running Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0?

Comment: You have an extra question mark for a sentence that is not a question. And, what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a bet and suggest you are using `Ruby 1.8.7` in which [`Math.log`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Math.html#method-c-log) takes only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Ruby are you using?

`Math.log` with 2 arguments is available only in Ruby 1.9+

Comment: Thanks, you right. Using an earlier version.